# Google Keyword Tool Results

Tags: json, keyword

I want to understand what this data is after I make a search query for "potato"
in google's keyword tool.

Its interesting because at the bottom it contains cost per click, names, suggestions, but the actual values for things like global searches are not definite.

Since its a bit long I paste it in here:
http://pastebin.com/UCTEhdB1

Any ideas are welcome.
Do not recommend any APIs

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the values from your pastebin are coming from [this tool](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal).

*I understand that this is not what you requested*, but, unfortunately, there does not appear to be any documentation on the data returned from the Keyword tool, which should be expected considering that Google offers the [Google Adwords API](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/) (unfortunately, a paid service).

Comment: Yea, not going to be paying for their api.